# Is the http server in the go libraries nonblocking?

Tags: go

I want a nonblocking http server for restful endpoints for my go project.  Will the server included in the go libs do the trick?

Comment: [`net/http.Serve`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Serve): "… creating a new service goroutine for each."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Go http package is concurrent, rather than nonblocking in the node.js sense. This means that the request handlers will not delay the processing of other requests even if they perform blocking operations. As Dave C said, it creates a new goroutine for each request. In practice, this means that you get the benefits of a nonblocking server without needing to worry about whether the code you write is blocking.